# What is the syntax of substring in Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to set the bg-color of a string-field so that if the value of the field starts with an 'R' it sets the background colour to red.  When the value is 'R080' the following expression works correctly:

```
=IF([Scored_Individual]="R080"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")
```

I would like to change this to be true when [Scored_Individual] starts with 'R'.  I have found that there is a subString function but the documentation for this is still to be written:  http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/SubStringExpression

I have tried the following:

- `=IF([Scored_Individual].substring(0)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].substring(1)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].substring(0,1)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].substring(0)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].substring(1)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].substring(0,1)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].subString(0)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].subString(1)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].subString(0,1)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].subString(0)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].subString(1)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].subString(0,1)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`

and all of the above again, but with == instead of =

I have also tried using left:

- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(0)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(1)="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(0)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(1)='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(0)=="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(1)=="R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(0)=='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`
- `=IF([Scored_Individual].left(1)=='R'; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")`

None of these worked.  How do you use substring?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRD uses OpenFormula, which is based on spreadsheet formulas as used by LibreOffice and Openoffice. Therefore you use the same logic as you would in OpenOffice (or Excel, for that matter).

```
=IF(LEFT([Scored_individual]; 1) = "R"; "#FF0000"; "#FFFFFF")
```